# Is there a way to make sealed classes generics?

Tags: kotlin

How a **generic** result or error type could be defined in Kotlin? Something like this example from TypeScript

```
type Errorneous<E, R> = 
  { is_error: true, error: E } | { is_error: false, result: R }

function calculate(): Errorneous<String, Number> { 
  return { is_error: false, result: 2 }
}
```

The problem is that Kotlin doesn't have generic sealed classes.

It's possible to define something like

```
data class Errorneous<E, R>(val error: E?, val result: R?)
```

But it not ideal as it allows wrong usage like

```
Errorneous<String, Int>(null, null)
Errorneous<String, Int>("", 2)
```

UPDATE

Possible (not compiling) Kotlin code

```
sealed class Errorneous
class Success<R>(val result: R) : Errorneous()
class Fail<R>(val error: R) : Errorneous()

fun calculate(): Errorneous {
  return Success(2)
}

fun main() {
  val result = calculate()
  if (result is Success<*>) { 
    val r: Int = result.result // <= Problem here, no smart cast
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem or the expectation. Sealed classes can define type parameters, so yes they can be made generic.

Comment: @Slaw please check the update question, I added Kotlin code

Comment: Is it expected that the `result` and `error` will always be the same type when returned by a function? And if so, why not have the property in the `Erroneous` class?

Comment: @Slaw - no, different types, it should be parameterised and be used as a results of different functions, if it was always the same type there was no need for generic. Can you please provide example with property in the Errorneous class, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I mean if, within the context of a single function, you have a possible return value of `Success<Int>` then is the other possible return value `Fail<Int>` or can it be `Fail<SomeArbitraryType>`?

Comment: @Slaw - for the single function it always will be single type.

Comment: @Slaw seems like it's indeed possible, please see comment by Rene

Comment: Then why not have `sealed class Erroneous<T>(val value: T) { abstract val isError: Boolean }` and simply have `Success<T>` and `Fail<T>` extend from that class? And then your function would be e.g. `fun calculate(): Erroneous<Int> { ... }`.

Comment: @Slaw thanks, will try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add generic parameters to the base class as well:

```
sealed class Errorneous<E,R>
class Error<E,R>(val error: E): Errorneous<E,R>()
class Success<E,R>(val result: R): Errorneous<E,R>()


fun calculate(): Errorneous<String, Int> {
    return Success(2)
}

fun main() {
    val result = calculate()
    if (result is Success<*, Int>) {
        val r: Int = result.result // <= smart cast
    }
}
```